# What does the `:e` and `:w` in `key:i1:e -> key2:i1:w` mean?

Tags: graphviz

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15707752/3416774), there are edges with `:e` and `:w` in the code:

```
key:i1:e -> key2:i1:w
```

What do they mean? I suppose they are this line in [The DOT Language | Graphviz](https://graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html):

> compass_pt     :   (n | ne | e | se | s | sw | w | nw | c | _)

But I don't understand this. Googling [`compass_pt GraphViz`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiXluf_iIbxAhVlNKYKHQ60DTsQFjADegQIDhAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F45916516%2Fgraphviz-specify-style-of-nodes-using-inline-notation&usg=AOvVaw1ZtkvQXAeAqz35XbO2X3SQ) doesn't yield any useful information.

Comment: see: https://graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#k:portPos

Comment: Try running `digraph G {
1:e -> 2:w;
3->4;
}` through webgraphviz.com and look at the generated graph. Now does it make sense?

Comment: @EricLippert I see. Anyway, FYI: [How does this (phishing) website has an identical domain with the authentic one?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/135675/52079)

Comment: I am curious to know how that phishing site managed to poison search results as well!

Comment: I also checked and yeah the names are identical ASCII characters. DNS cache poisoning is my best guess but this is not my area of expertise where security is concerned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#k:portPos
Ports are used to explicitly position head/tail of edges.  Ports are specified by compass points n(north), sw (southwest), etc and denote where on a node the edge is to terminate.

```
graph p {
 // node names (e.g. ne) are not Graphviz instructions, but are just for the reader
 n--P:n
 ne--P:ne
 nw--P:nw
 s--P:s
 se--P:se
 sw--P:sw
 w--P:w
 e--P:e
 c--P:c
 }
```

gives:
[image]