# How to position the legend at the bottom right of the graph?

Tags: html-table, label, legend, graphviz, dot

I want to [make a Legend/Key in GraphViz](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3499056/3416774). I make one successfully, but then how can I position it at the bottom right corner of the graph? I try using [`pos`](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:pos) but it doesn't work (it seems like it's only applicable in neato). This is my test code:

```
digraph {
    rankdir="LR";
    a -> b -> c -> a
    subgraph cluster_Legend { 
    label = "Legend";
    rank=same;
    e -> f
}
```

[image]

---

Normally, if the legend is actually an HTML table embeded in the lable, one can use `labelloc="b" labeljust="r"`. However, in my case the items to be explained in the legends are edges, not nodes, so my legend needs to consist two tables. Therefore using `labelloc` only moves the texts in the legend box, not the legend box itself.

My legend can be coded in two forms: table and non-table

### Table version

```
digraph {    
    subgraph clusterLegend { 
    rank = sink;
    label = "Legend";
    fontsize = 20
    node [ color="white" ]
    {rank=same; key, key2}
    key [ label=<<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" cellborder="0">
      <tr><td align="right" port="i1">A</td></tr>
      <tr><td align="right" port="i2">A</td></tr>
      </table>> ]
    key2 [ label=<<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" cellborder="0">
      <tr><td align="left" port="i1">B</td><td>     The reason for A is B</td></tr>
      <tr><td align="left" port="i2">B</td><td>     The solution for A is B</td></tr>
      </table>>]
    key:i1 -> key2:i1 
    key:i2 -> key2:i2 [ arrowhead="odiamond" style=dashed ]
   }
}
```

### Non-table version

```
{rank=same; a1, b1 }
    {rank=same; a2, b2 }
    a1 [label="A"]
    a2 [label="A"]
    b1 [label="B        The reason for A is B"]
    b2 [label="B        The solution for A is B"]
    a1 -> b1 [ minlen=4 ]
    a2 -> b2 [ minlen=4 arrowhead="odiamond" style=dashed ]
```

[image]

I think if we are to use `labelloc` and `labeljust`, then we need to figure out how to put arrows as items of table. [Is there a way to do so?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67900606/3416774)

This is my [real graph](https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/#digraph%20%7B%0A%09rankdir%3D%22TB%22%3B%0A%09splines%3Dortho%3B%0A%09overlap%3Dfalse%3B%0A%09nodesep%3D%220.2%22%3B%0A%09ranksep%3D%220.4%22%3B%0A%09label%3D%22C%C3%A2y%20v%E1%BA%A5n%20%C4%91%E1%BB%81%20trong%20vi%E1%BB%87c%20ph%C3%A1t%20tri%E1%BB%83n%20d%E1%BB%B1%20%C3%A1n%20Qu%E1%BA%A3%20C%E1%BA%A7u%22%3B%0A%09fontsize%20%3D%2030%0A%09labelloc%3D%22t%22%3B%0A%09fontname%3D%22Lato%22%3B%0A%09node%20%5B%20shape%3D%22plaintext%22%20style%3D%22filled%2C%20rounded%22%20fontname%3D%22Lato%22%20margin%3D0.2%20%5D%0A%09edge%20%5B%20fontname%3D%22Lato%22%20color%3D%22%232B303A%22%20%5D%0A%09V%E1%BA%A5n_%C4%91%E1%BB%81_trung_t%C3%A2m%20%5B%20label%3D%22Qu%C3%A1%20nhi%E1%BB%81u%20vi%E1%BB%87c%22%20fillcolor%3D%22%23DB2955%22%20fontcolor%3D%22%23ffffff%22%20%5D%0A%09V%E1%BA%A5n_%C4%91%E1%BB%81_trung_t%C3%A2m2%20%5B%20label%3D%22L%E1%BA%A1i%20l%C3%A0%20qu%C3%A1%20nhi%E1%BB%81u%20vi%E1%BB%87c%22%20fillcolor%3D%22%23DB2955%22%20fontcolor%3D%22%23ffffff%22%20%5D%0A%09%0A%09%2F%2FB%E1%BA%BF%20t%E1%BA%AFc%0A%09node%20%5B%20color%3D%22%232B303A%22%20fontcolor%3D%22%23ffffff%22%20%5D%0A%09%22Hi%E1%BB%87n%20t%C6%B0%E1%BB%A3ng%20%C4%91%E1%BB%93ng%20%C3%A2m%20kh%C3%A1c%20ngh%C4%A9a%5Cn%C4%91%C3%B2i%20h%E1%BB%8Fi%20h%E1%BB%8D%20ph%E1%BA%A3i%20r%E1%BA%A5t%20ki%C3%AAn%20nh%E1%BA%ABn%5Cntranh%20lu%E1%BA%ADn%20%C4%91%E1%BA%BFn%20c%C3%B9ng%22%0A%09%22%C4%90%E1%BB%83%20c%C3%B3%20s%E1%BB%B1%20%C4%91%E1%BB%99t%20ph%C3%A1%20c%E1%BA%A7n%20k%E1%BA%BFt%20n%E1%BB%91i%5Cnnhi%E1%BB%81u%20l%C4%A9nh%20v%E1%BB%B1c%20l%E1%BA%A1i%20v%E1%BB%9Bi%20nhau%22%20%0A%09%22Ch%E1%BB%89%20n%E1%BB%99i%20vi%E1%BB%87c%20r%E1%BB%ADa%20b%C3%A1t%20sau%20khi%20%C4%83n%5Cnc%C5%A9ng%20%C4%91%C3%A3%20l%C3%A0%20m%E1%BB%99t%20th%E1%BB%A9%20l%C3%A0m%20nh%E1%BB%A9c%20%C4%91%E1%BA%A7u%22%0A%09%2F%2F%20%22Ph%E1%BA%A3i%20m%E1%BA%A5t%2010%20n%C4%83m%20%C4%91%E1%BB%83%20n%E1%BA%AFm%20%C4%91%C6%B0%E1%BB%A3c%20nh%E1%BB%AFng%20v%E1%BA%A5n%20%C4%91%E1%BB%81%20c%E1%BA%A7n%20thi%E1%BA%BFt.%5CnN%E1%BA%BFu%20%C4%91%E1%BB%83%20ti%E1%BA%BFp%20theo%20th%C3%AC%20bao%20gi%E1%BB%9D%3F%22%20%0A%09%0A%09%2F%2FH%C3%A0nh%20%C4%91%E1%BB%99ng%0A%09node%20%5B%20color%3D%22%23ED96AC%22%20fontcolor%3D%22%23000000%22%20%5D%0A%09C%E1%BA%A7n_1a%20%5B%20label%3D%22C%E1%BA%A7n%20t%C3%ACm%20hi%E1%BB%83u%20s%C3%A2u%20h%C6%A1n%5Cn%C4%91%E1%BB%91i%20t%C6%B0%E1%BB%A3ng%20c%E1%BB%A7a%20m%C3%ACnh%22%20%5D%0A%09C%E1%BA%A7n_1b%20%5B%20label%3D%22C%E1%BA%A7n%20nghi%C3%AAn%20c%E1%BB%A9u%20s%C3%A2u%20h%C6%A1n%22%20%5D%0A%09C%E1%BA%A7n_1c%20%5B%20label%3D%22C%E1%BA%A7n%20nh%E1%BA%AFn%20h%E1%BB%8Fi%20t%E1%BB%ABng%20ng%C6%B0%E1%BB%9Di%20m%E1%BB%99t%22%20%5D%0A%09C%E1%BA%A7n_1d%20%5B%20label%3D%22C%E1%BA%A7n%20%C4%91%C4%83ng%20b%C3%A0i%20nhi%E1%BB%81u%20h%C6%A1n%22%20%5D%0A%09C%E1%BA%A7n_1e%20%5B%20label%3D%22C%E1%BA%A7n%20khi%E1%BA%BFn%20h%E1%BB%8D%20mu%E1%BB%91n%20chia%20s%E1%BA%BB%20h%C6%A1n%22%20%5D%0A%09node%20%5B%20color%3D%22%23ABD2FA%22%20%5D%0A%09C%E1%BA%A7n_2a%20%5B%20label%3D%22C%E1%BA%A7n%20b%E1%BA%AFt%20%C4%91%E1%BA%A7u%20t%E1%BB%AB%20nh%E1%BB%AFng%20ng%C6%B0%E1%BB%9Di%5Cnr%E1%BA%A5t%20mu%E1%BB%91n%20n%C3%B3i%20v%E1%BB%81%20%C4%91i%E1%BB%81u%20n%C3%A0y%22%20%5D%0A%09C%E1%BA%A7n_2b%20%5B%20label%3D%22%C4%90%E1%BB%8Bnh%20v%E1%BB%8B%20b%E1%BA%A3n%20th%C3%A2n%20nh%C6%B0%20l%C3%A0%5Cnng%C6%B0%E1%BB%9Di%20n%C3%B3i%20l%C3%AAn%20ti%E1%BA%BFng%20n%C3%B3i%5Cnho%E1%BA%B7c%20b%E1%BA%A3o%20v%E1%BB%87%20quy%E1%BB%81n%20c%E1%BB%A7a%20h%E1%BB%8D%22%20%5D%0A%09%0A%20%20%09node%20%5B%20color%3D%22%23C6CCD2%22%20%5D%0A%09V%E1%BA%A5n_%C4%91%E1%BB%81_trung_t%C3%A2m%20-%3E%20%22Thi%E1%BA%BFu%20ng%C6%B0%E1%BB%9Di%20ph%E1%BB%A5%22%20%0A%09V%E1%BA%A5n_%C4%91%E1%BB%81_trung_t%C3%A2m%20-%3E%20%22Qu%C3%A1%20nhi%E1%BB%81u%20ch%E1%BB%A7%20%C4%91%E1%BB%81%20c%E1%BA%A7n%20nghi%C3%AAn%20c%E1%BB%A9u%22%20%0A%09C%E1%BA%A7n_1a%20-%3E%20C%E1%BA%A7n_1c%20%5B%20arrowhead%3D%22odiamond%22%20style%3D%22dashed%22%20%5D%0A%09C%E1%BA%A7n_1e%20-%3E%20C%E1%BA%A7n_1c%20%5B%20arrowhead%3D%22odiamond%22%20style%3D%22dashed%22%20%5D%0A%09C%E1%BA%A7n_1c%20-%3E%20V%E1%BA%A5n_%C4%91%E1%BB%81_trung_t%C3%A2m2%20%5B%20arrowhead%3D%22odiamond%22%20style%3D%22dashed%22%20%5D%0A%09C%E1%BA%A7n_1b%20-%3E%20V%E1%BA%A5n_%C4%91%E1%BB%81_trung_t%C3%A2m2%20%5B%20arrowhead%3D%22odiamond%22%20style%3D%22dashed%22%20%5D%0A%09C%E1%BA%A7n_1d%20-%3E%20V%E1%BA%A5n_%C4%91%E1%BB%81_trung_t%C3%A2m2%20%5B%20arrowhead%3D%22odiamond%22%20style%3D%22dashed%22%20%5D%0A%09C%E1%BA%A7n_2a%20-%3E%20C%E1%BA%A7n_2b%20%5B%20arrowhead%3D%22odiamond%22%20style%3D%22dashed%22%20%5D%0A%09%22Qu%C3%A1%20nhi%E1%BB%81u%20ch%E1%BB%A7%20%C4%91%E1%BB%81%20c%E1%BA%A7n%20nghi%C3%AAn%20c%E1%BB%A9u%22%20-%3E%20%22%C4%90%E1%BB%83%20c%C3%B3%20s%E1%BB%B1%20%C4%91%E1%BB%99t%20ph%C3%A1%20c%E1%BA%A7n%20k%E1%BA%BFt%20n%E1%BB%91i%5Cnnhi%E1%BB%81u%20l%C4%A9nh%20v%E1%BB%B1c%20l%E1%BA%A1i%20v%E1%BB%9Bi%20nhau%22%20%0A%09%22Ng%C6%B0%E1%BB%9Di%20xem%20c%E1%BA%A3m%20th%E1%BA%A5y%20ch%E1%BB%A7%20%C4%91%E1%BB%81%5Cnxa%20l%E1%BA%A1%20v%E1%BB%9Bi%20nhu%20c%E1%BA%A7u%20c%E1%BB%A7a%20h%E1%BB%8D%22%20-%3E%20%22Qu%C3%A1%20nhi%E1%BB%81u%20ch%E1%BB%A7%20%C4%91%E1%BB%81%20c%E1%BA%A7n%20nghi%C3%AAn%20c%E1%BB%A9u%22%0A%09%22Thi%E1%BA%BFu%20ng%C6%B0%E1%BB%9Di%20ph%E1%BB%A5%22%20-%3E%20%22Kh%C3%B4ng%20c%C3%B3%20nhi%E1%BB%81u%20t%C3%ACnh%20nguy%E1%BB%87n%20vi%C3%AAn%22%20%0A%09%22Thi%E1%BA%BFu%20ng%C6%B0%E1%BB%9Di%20ph%E1%BB%A5%22%20-%3E%20%22Kh%C3%B4ng%20c%C3%B3%20ti%E1%BB%81n%20%C4%91%E1%BB%83%20thu%C3%AA%20d%E1%BB%8Bch%20v%E1%BB%A5%22%20%0A%09%0A%09%2F%2F%20these%20clusters%20enforce%20the%20correct%20hierarchies%0A%09subgraph%20level_1%20%7B%0A%09%09rank%3Dsame%3B%0A%09%09%22Thi%E1%BA%BFu%20ng%C6%B0%E1%BB%9Di%20ph%E1%BB%A5%22%20%0A%09%09%22Qu%C3%A1%20nhi%E1%BB%81u%20ch%E1%BB%A7%20%C4%91%E1%BB%81%20c%E1%BA%A7n%20nghi%C3%AAn%20c%E1%BB%A9u%22%20%0A%09%7D%0A%09%0A%09subgraph%20branch_Kh%C3%B4ng_c%C3%B3_nhi%E1%BB%81u_t%C3%ACnh_nguy%E1%BB%87n_vi%C3%AAn%20%7B%0A%09%09%22Kh%C3%B4ng%20c%C3%B3%20nhi%E1%BB%81u%20t%C3%ACnh%20nguy%E1%BB%87n%20vi%C3%AAn%22%20-%3E%20%22Ng%C6%B0%E1%BB%9Di%20xem%20kh%C3%B4ng%20th%E1%BA%A5y%20%C4%91%C3%A1ng%20quan%20t%C3%A2m%22%20%20%0A%09%09%22Ng%C6%B0%E1%BB%9Di%20xem%20kh%C3%B4ng%20th%E1%BA%A5y%20%C4%91%C3%A1ng%20quan%20t%C3%A2m%22%20%20-%3E%20%22Ng%C6%B0%E1%BB%9Di%20xem%20c%E1%BA%A3m%20th%E1%BA%A5y%20ch%E1%BB%A7%20%C4%91%E1%BB%81%5Cnxa%20l%E1%BA%A1%20v%E1%BB%9Bi%20nhu%20c%E1%BA%A7u%20c%E1%BB%A7a%20h%E1%BB%8D%22%20%0A%09%09%22Ng%C6%B0%E1%BB%9Di%20xem%20kh%C3%B4ng%20th%E1%BA%A5y%20%C4%91%C3%A1ng%20quan%20t%C3%A2m%22%20-%3E%20%22H%E1%BB%8D%20c%E1%BA%A3m%20th%E1%BA%A5y%20%C3%BD%20t%C6%B0%E1%BB%9Fng%20%C4%91i%20ng%C6%B0%E1%BB%A3c%20l%E1%BA%A1i%20ni%E1%BB%81m%20tin%20c%E1%BB%A7a%20h%E1%BB%8D%22%0A%09%09%22H%E1%BB%8D%20c%E1%BA%A3m%20th%E1%BA%A5y%20%C3%BD%20t%C6%B0%E1%BB%9Fng%20%C4%91i%20ng%C6%B0%E1%BB%A3c%20l%E1%BA%A1i%20ni%E1%BB%81m%20tin%20c%E1%BB%A7a%20h%E1%BB%8D%22%20-%3E%20%22Hi%E1%BB%87n%20t%C6%B0%E1%BB%A3ng%20%C4%91%E1%BB%93ng%20%C3%A2m%20kh%C3%A1c%20ngh%C4%A9a%5Cn%C4%91%C3%B2i%20h%E1%BB%8Fi%20h%E1%BB%8D%20ph%E1%BA%A3i%20r%E1%BA%A5t%20ki%C3%AAn%20nh%E1%BA%ABn%5Cntranh%20lu%E1%BA%ADn%20%C4%91%E1%BA%BFn%20c%C3%B9ng%22%0A%09%09%22H%E1%BB%8D%20c%E1%BA%A3m%20th%E1%BA%A5y%20%C3%BD%20t%C6%B0%E1%BB%9Fng%20%C4%91i%20ng%C6%B0%E1%BB%A3c%20l%E1%BA%A1i%20ni%E1%BB%81m%20tin%20c%E1%BB%A7a%20h%E1%BB%8D%22%20-%3E%20%22H%E1%BB%8D%20kh%C3%B4ng%20mu%E1%BB%91n%20tranh%20lu%E1%BA%ADn%22%0A%09%09%22H%E1%BB%8D%20kh%C3%B4ng%20mu%E1%BB%91n%20tranh%20lu%E1%BA%ADn%22%20-%3E%20%22Hi%E1%BB%87n%20t%C6%B0%E1%BB%A3ng%20%C4%91%E1%BB%93ng%20%C3%A2m%20kh%C3%A1c%20ngh%C4%A9a%5Cn%C4%91%C3%B2i%20h%E1%BB%8Fi%20h%E1%BB%8D%20ph%E1%BA%A3i%20r%E1%BA%A5t%20ki%C3%AAn%20nh%E1%BA%ABn%5Cntranh%20lu%E1%BA%ADn%20%C4%91%E1%BA%BFn%20c%C3%B9ng%22%0A%09%09%22H%E1%BB%8D%20kh%C3%B4ng%20mu%E1%BB%91n%20tranh%20lu%E1%BA%ADn%22%20-%3E%20C%E1%BA%A7n_2a%20%5Barrowhead%3D%22odiamond%22%20style%3D%22dashed%22%5D%0A%09%09%22H%E1%BB%8D%20kh%C3%B4ng%20mu%E1%BB%91n%20tranh%20lu%E1%BA%ADn%22%20-%3E%20%22Ng%C6%B0%E1%BB%9Di%20xem%20kh%C3%B4ng%20th%E1%BA%A5y%20%C4%91%C3%A1ng%20quan%20t%C3%A2m%22%0A%09%09%22Kh%C3%B4ng%20c%C3%B3%20nhi%E1%BB%81u%20t%C3%ACnh%20nguy%E1%BB%87n%20vi%C3%AAn%22%20-%3E%20%22Ng%C6%B0%E1%BB%9Di%20xem%20mu%E1%BB%91n%20gi%C3%BAp%5Cnnh%C6%B0ng%20kh%C3%B4ng%20c%C3%B3%20th%E1%BB%9Di%20gian%22%0A%09%09%22Ng%C6%B0%E1%BB%9Di%20xem%20mu%E1%BB%91n%20gi%C3%BAp%5Cnnh%C6%B0ng%20kh%C3%B4ng%20c%C3%B3%20th%E1%BB%9Di%20gian%22%20-%3E%20C%E1%BA%A7n_1e%20%5B%20arrowhead%3D%22odiamond%22%20style%3D%22dashed%22%20%5D%0A%09%09%22Kh%C3%B4ng%20c%C3%B3%20nhi%E1%BB%81u%20t%C3%ACnh%20nguy%E1%BB%87n%20vi%C3%AAn%22%20-%3E%20%22Ch%C6%B0a%20qu%E1%BA%A3ng%20c%C3%A1o%20tuy%E1%BB%83n%20d%E1%BB%A5ng%20nhi%E1%BB%81u%22%0A%09%09%22Ch%C6%B0a%20qu%E1%BA%A3ng%20c%C3%A1o%20tuy%E1%BB%83n%20d%E1%BB%A5ng%20nhi%E1%BB%81u%22%20-%3E%20C%E1%BA%A7n_1d%20%5B%20arrowhead%3D%22odiamond%22%20style%3D%22dashed%22%20%5D%0A%09%09%2F%2F%20%22Ch%C6%B0a%20qu%E1%BA%A3ng%20c%C3%A1o%20tuy%E1%BB%83n%20d%E1%BB%A5ng%20nhi%E1%BB%81u%22%20-%3E%20%22%C4%90%C4%83ng%20m%E1%BA%A5y%20b%C3%A0i%20kh%C3%A1c%20c%C5%A9ng%5Cnch%E1%BA%B3ng%20th%E1%BA%A5y%20t%C6%B0%C6%A1ng%20t%C3%A1c%20m%E1%BA%A5y%22%20%0A%09%7D%0A%09subgraph%20level_2%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%09rank%3Dsame%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%09rankdir%3DLR%3B%0A%09%09%22Kh%C3%B4ng%20c%C3%B3%20ti%E1%BB%81n%20%C4%91%E1%BB%83%20thu%C3%AA%20d%E1%BB%8Bch%20v%E1%BB%A5%22%3B%0A%09%09%22Kh%C3%B4ng%20c%C3%B3%20nhi%E1%BB%81u%20t%C3%ACnh%20nguy%E1%BB%87n%20vi%C3%AAn%22%3B%0A%09%09%22Kh%C3%B4ng%20c%C3%B3%20nhi%E1%BB%81u%20t%C3%ACnh%20nguy%E1%BB%87n%20vi%C3%AAn%22%20-%3E%20%22Kh%C3%B4ng%20c%C3%B3%20ti%E1%BB%81n%20%C4%91%E1%BB%83%20thu%C3%AA%20d%E1%BB%8Bch%20v%E1%BB%A5%22%20%5B%20style%3Dinvis%20%5D%0A%20%20%09%7D%0A%09subgraph%20level_3%20%7B%0A%09%09rank%3Dsame%3B%0A%09%09%22Ch%C6%B0a%20l%C3%A0m%20workshop%20%C4%91%C6%B0%E1%BB%A3c%22%0A%09%09%22Kh%C3%B4ng%20%C4%91i%20l%C3%A0m%20b%C3%AAn%20ngo%C3%A0i%20%C4%91%C6%B0%E1%BB%A3c%22%0A%09%09%22Ng%C6%B0%E1%BB%9Di%20xem%20kh%C3%B4ng%20th%E1%BA%A5y%20%C4%91%C3%A1ng%20quan%20t%C3%A2m%22%20%20%0A%09%09%22Ng%C6%B0%E1%BB%9Di%20xem%20mu%E1%BB%91n%20gi%C3%BAp%5Cnnh%C6%B0ng%20kh%C3%B4ng%20c%C3%B3%20th%E1%BB%9Di%20gian%22%20%0A%09%7D%0A%09subgraph%20branch_Kh%C3%B4ng_c%C3%B3_ti%E1%BB%81n_%C4%91%E1%BB%83_thu%C3%AA_d%E1%BB%8Bch_v%E1%BB%A5%20%7B%0A%09%09%22Kh%C3%B4ng%20c%C3%B3%20ti%E1%BB%81n%20%C4%91%E1%BB%83%20thu%C3%AA%20d%E1%BB%8Bch%20v%E1%BB%A5%22%20-%3E%20%22Ch%C6%B0a%20l%C3%A0m%20workshop%20%C4%91%C6%B0%E1%BB%A3c%22%0A%09%09%22Ch%C6%B0a%20l%C3%A0m%20workshop%20%C4%91%C6%B0%E1%BB%A3c%22%20-%3E%20%22Th%E1%BA%A5y%20nhi%E1%BB%81u%20l%E1%BB%97%20h%E1%BB%95ng%20ki%E1%BA%BFn%5Cnth%E1%BB%A9c%2C%20s%E1%BB%A3%20ch%E1%BB%89%20sai%20%C4%91%C6%B0%E1%BB%9Dng%22%0A%09%09%22Th%E1%BA%A5y%20nhi%E1%BB%81u%20l%E1%BB%97%20h%E1%BB%95ng%20ki%E1%BA%BFn%5Cnth%E1%BB%A9c%2C%20s%E1%BB%A3%20ch%E1%BB%89%20sai%20%C4%91%C6%B0%E1%BB%9Dng%22%20-%3E%20C%E1%BA%A7n_1b%20%5B%20arrowhead%3D%22odiamond%22%20style%3D%22dashed%22%20%5D%0A%09%09%22Th%E1%BA%A5y%20nhi%E1%BB%81u%20l%E1%BB%97%20h%E1%BB%95ng%20ki%E1%BA%BFn%5Cnth%E1%BB%A9c%2C%20s%E1%BB%A3%20ch%E1%BB%89%20sai%20%C4%91%C6%B0%E1%BB%9Dng%22%20-%3E%20%22Li%C3%AAn%20h%E1%BB%87%20v%E1%BB%9Bi%20chuy%C3%AAn%20gia%5Cn%C4%91%E1%BB%83%20%C4%91%C6%B0%E1%BB%A3c%20c%E1%BB%91%20v%E1%BA%A5n%22%0A%09%09%22Li%C3%AAn%20h%E1%BB%87%20v%E1%BB%9Bi%20chuy%C3%AAn%20gia%5Cn%C4%91%E1%BB%83%20%C4%91%C6%B0%E1%BB%A3c%20c%E1%BB%91%20v%E1%BA%A5n%22%20-%3E%20C%E1%BA%A7n_1c%20%5B%20arrowhead%3D%22odiamond%22%20style%3D%22dashed%22%20%5D%0A%09%09%22Ch%C6%B0a%20l%C3%A0m%20workshop%20%C4%91%C6%B0%E1%BB%A3c%22%20-%3E%20%22Ng%C6%B0%E1%BB%9Di%20ngo%C3%A0i%20c%E1%BA%A7n%20th%E1%BA%A5y%20c%C3%B3%20c%C3%A1i%20b%E1%BA%B1ng%20%C4%91%E1%BB%83%20tin%22%0A%09%09%22Ng%C6%B0%E1%BB%9Di%20ngo%C3%A0i%20c%E1%BA%A7n%20th%E1%BA%A5y%20c%C3%B3%20c%C3%A1i%20b%E1%BA%B1ng%20%C4%91%E1%BB%83%20tin%22%20-%3E%20C%E1%BA%A7n_2a%20%5B%20arrowhead%3D%22odiamond%22%20style%3D%22dashed%22%20%5D%0A%09%09%22Kh%C3%B4ng%20c%C3%B3%20ti%E1%BB%81n%20%C4%91%E1%BB%83%20thu%C3%AA%20d%E1%BB%8Bch%20v%E1%BB%A5%22%20-%3E%20%22Nh%E1%BB%AFng%20ng%C6%B0%E1%BB%9Di%20theo%20d%C3%B5i%5Cnl%C3%A2u%20kh%C3%B4ng%20%E1%BB%A7ng%20h%E1%BB%99%20ti%E1%BB%81n%22%20%0A%09%09%22Nh%E1%BB%AFng%20ng%C6%B0%E1%BB%9Di%20theo%20d%C3%B5i%5Cnl%C3%A2u%20kh%C3%B4ng%20%E1%BB%A7ng%20h%E1%BB%99%20ti%E1%BB%81n%22%20-%3E%20%22Ch%C6%B0a%20%C4%91%C4%83ng%20b%C3%A0i%20k%C3%AAu%20g%E1%BB%8Di%5Cn%E1%BB%A7ng%20h%E1%BB%99%20tr%C3%AAn%20Facebook%22%0A%09%09%22Ch%C6%B0a%20%C4%91%C4%83ng%20b%C3%A0i%20k%C3%AAu%20g%E1%BB%8Di%5Cn%E1%BB%A7ng%20h%E1%BB%99%20tr%C3%AAn%20Facebook%22%20-%3E%20%22%C4%90%C4%83ng%20m%E1%BA%A5y%20b%C3%A0i%20kh%C3%A1c%20c%C5%A9ng%5Cnch%E1%BA%B3ng%20th%E1%BA%A5y%20t%C6%B0%C6%A1ng%20t%C3%A1c%20m%E1%BA%A5y%22%20%0A%09%09%22Ch%C6%B0a%20%C4%91%C4%83ng%20b%C3%A0i%20k%C3%AAu%20g%E1%BB%8Di%5Cn%E1%BB%A7ng%20h%E1%BB%99%20tr%C3%AAn%20Facebook%22%20-%3E%20C%E1%BA%A7n_1d%20%5B%20arrowhead%3D%22odiamond%22%20style%3D%22dashed%22%20%5D%0A%09%09%22%C4%90%C4%83ng%20m%E1%BA%A5y%20b%C3%A0i%20kh%C3%A1c%20c%C5%A9ng%5Cnch%E1%BA%B3ng%20th%E1%BA%A5y%20t%C6%B0%C6%A1ng%20t%C3%A1c%20m%E1%BA%A5y%22%20-%3E%20C%E1%BA%A7n_1a%20%5B%20arrowhead%3D%22odiamond%22%20style%3D%22dashed%22%20%5D%0A%09%09%22Ng%C6%B0%E1%BB%9Di%20xem%20c%E1%BA%A3m%20th%E1%BA%A5y%20ch%E1%BB%A7%20%C4%91%E1%BB%81%5Cnxa%20l%E1%BA%A1%20v%E1%BB%9Bi%20nhu%20c%E1%BA%A7u%20c%E1%BB%A7a%20h%E1%BB%8D%22%20-%3E%20C%E1%BA%A7n_1a%20%5B%20arrowhead%3D%22odiamond%22%20style%3D%22dashed%22%20%5D%0A%09%09%22Ng%C6%B0%E1%BB%9Di%20xem%20c%E1%BA%A3m%20th%E1%BA%A5y%20ch%E1%BB%A7%20%C4%91%E1%BB%81%5Cnxa%20l%E1%BA%A1%20v%E1%BB%9Bi%20nhu%20c%E1%BA%A7u%20c%E1%BB%A7a%20h%E1%BB%8D%22%20-%3E%20C%E1%BA%A7n_2a%20%5B%20arrowhead%3D%22odiamond%22%20style%3D%22dashed%22%20%5D%0A%09%09%22Kh%C3%B4ng%20c%C3%B3%20ti%E1%BB%81n%20%C4%91%E1%BB%83%20thu%C3%AA%20d%E1%BB%8Bch%20v%E1%BB%A5%22%20-%3E%20%22Kh%C3%B4ng%20%C4%91i%20l%C3%A0m%20b%C3%AAn%20ngo%C3%A0i%20%C4%91%C6%B0%E1%BB%A3c%22%0A%09%09%22Kh%C3%B4ng%20%C4%91i%20l%C3%A0m%20b%C3%AAn%20ngo%C3%A0i%20%C4%91%C6%B0%E1%BB%A3c%22%20-%3E%20%22Qu%C3%A1%20nhi%E1%BB%81u%20ch%E1%BB%A7%20%C4%91%E1%BB%81%20c%E1%BA%A7n%20nghi%C3%AAn%20c%E1%BB%A9u%22%0A%09%09%22Kh%C3%B4ng%20%C4%91i%20l%C3%A0m%20b%C3%AAn%20ngo%C3%A0i%20%C4%91%C6%B0%E1%BB%A3c%22%20-%3E%20%22Ph%E1%BA%A3i%20l%C3%A0%20m%E1%BB%99t%20d%E1%BB%B1%20%C3%A1n%20to%C3%A0n%20th%E1%BB%9Di%20gian%22%0A%09%09%22Ph%E1%BA%A3i%20l%C3%A0%20m%E1%BB%99t%20d%E1%BB%B1%20%C3%A1n%20to%C3%A0n%20th%E1%BB%9Di%20gian%22%20-%3E%20%22Ch%E1%BB%89%20n%E1%BB%99i%20vi%E1%BB%87c%20r%E1%BB%ADa%20b%C3%A1t%20sau%20khi%20%C4%83n%5Cnc%C5%A9ng%20%C4%91%C3%A3%20l%C3%A0%20m%E1%BB%99t%20th%E1%BB%A9%20l%C3%A0m%20nh%E1%BB%A9c%20%C4%91%E1%BA%A7u%22%20%0A%09%09%22Kh%C3%B4ng%20c%C3%B3%20ti%E1%BB%81n%20%C4%91%E1%BB%83%20thu%C3%AA%20d%E1%BB%8Bch%20v%E1%BB%A5%22%20-%3E%20%22Ch%C6%B0a%20t%C3%ACm%20%C4%91%C6%B0%E1%BB%A3c%20qu%E1%BB%B9%5Cnnghi%C3%AAn%20c%E1%BB%A9u%20%C4%91%C3%BAng%20nhu%20c%E1%BA%A7u%22%0A%09%09%22Ch%C6%B0a%20t%C3%ACm%20%C4%91%C6%B0%E1%BB%A3c%20qu%E1%BB%B9%5Cnnghi%C3%AAn%20c%E1%BB%A9u%20%C4%91%C3%BAng%20nhu%20c%E1%BA%A7u%22%20-%3E%20C%E1%BA%A7n_1b%20%5B%20arrowhead%3D%22odiamond%22%20style%3D%22dashed%22%20%5D%0A%09%7D%0A%09%0A%09splines%20%3D%20true%3B%0A%09subgraph%20clusterLegend%20%7B%20%0A%09rank%20%3D%20sink%3B%0A%20%20%20%20label%20%3D%20%22Ch%C3%BA%20th%C3%ADch%22%3B%0A%09fontsize%20%3D%2020%0A%09node%20%5B%20color%3D%22white%22%20%5D%0A%09%7Brank%3Dsame%3B%20key%2C%20key2%2C%20key3%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20key%20%5Blabel%3D%3C%3Ctable%20border%3D%220%22%20cellpadding%3D%222%22%20cellspacing%3D%220%22%20cellborder%3D%220%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%20align%3D%22right%22%20port%3D%22i1%22%3EA%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%20align%3D%22right%22%20port%3D%22i2%22%3EA%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftable%3E%3E%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%20key2%20%5Blabel%3D%3C%3Ctable%20border%3D%220%22%20cellpadding%3D%222%22%20cellspacing%3D%220%22%20cellborder%3D%220%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%20port%3D%22i1%22%3EB%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%20port%3D%22i2%22%3EB%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftable%3E%3E%5D%0A%09key3%20%5Blabel%3D%3C%3Ctable%20border%3D%220%22%20cellpadding%3D%222%22%20cellspacing%3D%220%22%20cellborder%3D%220%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%20align%3D%22left%22%20port%3D%22i1%22%3EL%C3%BD%20do%20c%E1%BB%A7a%20A%20l%C3%A0%20B%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%20align%3D%22left%22%20port%3D%22i2%22%3E%C4%90%E1%BB%83%20gi%E1%BA%A3i%20quy%E1%BA%BFt%20A%20c%E1%BA%A7n%20l%C3%A0m%20B%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftable%3E%3E%5D%0A%20%20%20%20key%3Ai1%20-%3E%20key2%3Ai1%20%0A%20%20%20%20key2%3Ai1%20-%3E%20key3%3Ai1%20%5Bstyle%3Dinvis%5D%0A%20%20%20%20key%3Ai2%20-%3E%20key2%3Ai2%20%5B%20arrowhead%3D%22odiamond%22%20style%3Ddashed%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%20key2%3Ai2%20-%3E%20key3%3Ai2%20%5Bstyle%3Dinvis%5D%0A%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D).

<sub>See more: [Placing Graphviz nodes in fixed positions / Magnus Jacobsson / Observable](https://observablehq.com/@magjac/placing-graphviz-nodes-in-fixed-positions)</sub>

Comment: Use labelloc and labeljust.  Here is previous discussion - https://forum.graphviz.org/t/adding-key-or-legend/351/2

Comment: Is there a way to not using label? Because if the legend consists two tables, then this doesn't seem to work. Please see my update

Answer (score 1):

You can draw additional invisible edges and node(s) at the bottom of the diagram and set them the [same rank](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/rank/) as the legend (also need to turn on the [`newrank`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/newrank/) attribute for graph). By adjusting the [height](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/height/) and [width](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/width/) of the invisible node(s), you can move the legend to the desired distance.

An image that shows the invisible:
[image: position the legend at the bottom right of the graph with showed hidden node and edge made with graphviz dot]

Final image:
[image: position the legend at the bottom right of the graph made with graphviz dot]

Script:

```
digraph {    
    newrank=true // enable ranking between nodes and clusters
    
    a->b->c
    
    subgraph clusterLegend { 
    rank = sink;
    label = "Legend";
    fontsize = 20
    node [ color="white" ]
    {rank=same; key; key2}
    key [ label=<<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" cellborder="0">
      <tr><td align="right" port="i1">A</td></tr>
      <tr><td align="right" port="i2">A</td></tr>
      </table>> ]
    key2 [ label=<<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" cellborder="0">
      <tr><td align="left" port="i1">B</td><td>     The reason for A is B</td></tr>
      <tr><td align="left" port="i2">B</td><td>     The solution for A is B</td></tr>
      </table>>]
    key:i1 -> key2:i1 
    key:i2 -> key2:i2 [ arrowhead="odiamond" style=dashed ]
    }
   
   // Invisible nodes and edges
    d [style=invis width=5 height=5]
    c->d [style=invis]
   
   // Setting a same rank between cluster and invisible node
   {rank=same;key;key2;d;}
}
```

Another variant is create two distinct graphs and use [gvpack](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/gvpack.1.pdf) to glue them together.